# Can I retest all installed CPAN modules?

Tags: perl, dependency-management, cpan, software-update

If a module `A` relies on module `B` and module `B` is upgraded, `A` may break due to changes. My idea is to retest both `A` and `B` after upgrading `B`.

I think the easiest way is just to retest everything that can be retested: download every installed module from CPAN and execute its test scripts.

Is there a way to download and retest?

If there is no way, are there any helpers/API so I can implement such tool?

I basically need to

- query what is installed (including version numbers)
- download and unpack exact versions
- execute tests

Comment: `cpan -l` gives you a list of installed cpan modules and versions, but the list includes modules which are bundled with Perl.  That's not necessarily a bad thing if the goal is to test everything.  The `cpanm` utility facilitates a `--test-only` mode, and allows you to specify a version.

Comment: It gets harder where you might be asking for a historical version that the module's author has chosen to delete from CPAN.  For a long time CPAN authors were encouraged to keep a tidy house by removing older versions. I don't know if this practice is still encouraged.

Comment: This issue should be resolved by an application's test suite and dependency tree. You should investigate further only if you find that your system isn't working.

Comment: @Borodin What about dependency updates which break system tools like `cpan/cpanp/cpanm` or `prove`? What about modules I update because they are outdated, but don't actually use?

Comment: @DavidO put your comments as an answer

Comment: @Borodin Also, such a tool is essentially extra test coverage I get for free, and it seems to be fairly easy to write.

Comment: @nponeccop : Posted it, along with a few other ideas.

Answer (score 4):

The `cpan` tool that ships with core Perl includes a `-l` option, that directs it to provide a list of installed modules. For example, the last 10 items in the list on my system:

```
$ cpan -l 2>/dev/null |tail -10
Test2::Event::Encoding  1.302073
Test2::Event::Bail  1.302073
Test2::Event::Exception 1.302073
Test2::Event::Subtest   1.302073
Test2::Event::Skip  1.302073
Test2::Event::Info  1.302073
Test2::Event::Diag  1.302073
Test2::Event::TAP::Version  1.302073
JSON::PP    2.27400_02
JSON::PP::Boolean   undef
```

As demonstrated here you get a list of modules and version numbers. Sometimes the tool doesn't find the version in META, and therefore will return `undef` for the version numbers.  CPAN authors should be on the lookout for these sorts of mistakes, as they make it harder for tools that wish to identify the version without compiling the module itself.

Once you have the modules and version numbers you can use the `cpanm` tool (provided by App::cpanm) with its `--test-only` option to pull down a module of a specific version and test it.  You can request a specific version like this:

```
cpanm Some::Module@0.9990
```

(Pulls down only version 0.9990 of the target module).

Where things get tricky are the following:  Perl ships with a bunch of modules, and some of them also receive updates via CPAN. The `cpan -l` tool will list all installed modules, including the ones that ship with Perl.

Also some of the modules listed are simply part of a larger distribution.

Another tool that can be useful to you, which has been bundled with Perl since 5.8.9, is `corelist`.  If you run this:

```
corelist File::Temp
```

You will get:  "`File::Temp was first released with perl v5.6.1`"

If you do this:

```
corelist JSON
```

You will get: "`JSON was not in CORE (or so I think)`"

So it is pretty simple to determine if a module you're looking at in your list is one that ships with Perl or not.  Use that information as you see fit.

Another thing you'll have to solve for is what to do about shared dependencies.  If the first thing you test is a Moose upgrade, you'll pull in half of CPAN (that's an exaggeration), and that will dirty your environment for testing other modules.  To mitigate this effect you have a few choices. One is to leverage `App::perlbrew` and its `lib` option to set up throwaway library space.  That way you can install a module and its dependencies in a destination designated by `perlbrew lib` and `perlbrew use`, and then throw it away when done to move on to the next library for testing.

However, there may be a better solution, of which I am not adequately familiar to document here: The toolchain used by CPAN smoke testers.  See [CPAN::Testers](http://search.cpan.org/~barbie/CPAN-Testers-0.07/lib/CPAN/Testers.pm) if you wish to pursue this strategy. The smoke testers have worked out relatively lightweight approaches to pulling down and testing modules with their dependencies in an automated fashion.

Finally, another issue you will encounter is that CPAN authors are the ones who decide which versions of their modules live on CPAN and which ones get deleted.  A few years ago CPAN authors were encouraged to keep their CPAN repositories clean by deleting old versions. I don't know if this practice is still encouraged, but it does mean that you cannot count on a specific version number still existing.  To solve for this problem you should probably maintain your own repository of the tarballs for all versions you have installed at a given moment in time.  The CPAN module framework [Pinto](http://search.cpan.org/~thaljef/Pinto-0.14/lib/Pinto.pm) helps with keeping versions of a module, pinning some to not update, and other useful tricks.

Answer (score 3):

If you download and extract distribution `B` and `cd` into that directory, you can use the [brewbuild](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Test-BrewBuild/bin/brewbuild) binary from my [Test::BrewBuild](https://metacpan.org/release/Test-BrewBuild) (NOTE: requires Perlbrew or Berrybrew) with the `-R` aka `--revdep` flag to test `B` as well as all distributions that require `B`:

```
~/repos/Mock-Sub $ brewbuild -R

reverse dependencies: Test::Module::CheckDep::Version, App::RPi::EnvUI, RPi::DigiPot::MCP4XXXX, Devel::Examine::Subs, PSGI::Hector, File::Edit::Portable, Devel::Trace::Subs

Test::Module::CheckDep::Version
5.26.1 :: PASS

App::RPi::EnvUI
5.26.1 :: FAIL

RPi::DigiPot::MCP4XXXX
5.26.1 :: FAIL

Devel::Examine::Subs
5.26.1 :: PASS

PSGI::Hector
5.26.1 :: PASS

File::Edit::Portable
5.26.1 :: PASS

Devel::Trace::Subs
5.26.1 :: PASS
```

I do this every time I update one of my CPAN distributions that have reverse dependencies, so I don't break any consumers of my dists.